# Is it possible to boot an encrypted Windows 7 from grub?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, multi-boot, disk-encryption

I have a laptop with dual boot, a windows 7 with encrypted partition and an Ubuntu 10.10. Now I understood that i can't mount encrypted partitions from Ubuntu, 'cause it's not a valid ntfs partition anymore. But i wonder whether i can boot this encrypted windows 7 from grub.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.  It is all explained very well [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/voy/archive/2006/10/13/building-a-dual-boot-system-with-windows-vista-bitlocker-protection-with-tpm-support.aspx).  A simpler alternative would be to stop using Bit Locker and start using [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/).  Bit Locker is plenty secure, but TrueCrypt is way more versatile and offers many more options.  Check out [this review](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/bitlocker-truecrypt-encryption,2587.html) between the Bit Locker and TrueCrypt, very informative.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but i forgot to mention an important detail that encryption software is Check Point which is installed by my company's IT. I understand from your answer that booting an encrypted windows or ubuntu is related with encryption software and works about integration of software and bootloader (for me grub).

Comment: @azer I am not familiar with "Check Point".  What does Check Point do that would prevent you from setting up your system in one of the ways the article I linked to describes?